# Add exposed copper to eagle board?

Tags: eaglecad, copper, copper-pour

I am new to using eagle. I want to put some exposed copper pads that I can solder to on my board. The catch is that they cannot have through holes. I tried just making polygons in the top layer, but I am unsure if I will be able to solder to that. Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to make polygons on the top and bottom stop masks. Use the "tStop" and "bStop" layers to do this, it will basically prevent the soldermask from being put on the area you specify with the polygon.