# Create open copper plane in EAGLE

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I need to redesign an old PCB and for that I want to put down a open copper plane that won't get covered by solder mask.

I tried it by creating a rectangle in the 'Pads'-Layer. The PCBs just arrived and.. well they are covered by soldermask.

I also tried the answer to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169514/add-exposed-copper-to-eagle-board) question but now my placed rectangle is gone and I can't see it anymore.

So the question is:
How do I create a copper plane without soldermask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soldermask is layer 29 and 30 (tStop/bStop).
Anything on those layers is not covered with soldermask.

Draw a polygon or shape on those layers.

Your current visible layerset might not show these layers.
Type: `display` and press enter or click the layers button to make them visible.

Comment: This solved it. I am now seeing it again. Thank you!